# I'm not finding something in the array ... why?

Tags: php, sql

I am querying a database to bring back staff numbers so that I can use this to validate entries in a form. I dump the result into an array and then when someone enters a number on the form I validate that it exists... it isn't working though and never finds the number. I think it's the way I'm creating the array.

```
$sql1 = "SELECT num FROM staff";
$data = array();
     $result1 = mysql_query($sql1, $conn) or die("db select error: " . $sql1);
      while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)){
          $data[]= $row1;
      }
var_dump($data);

$needle = 7034252;
if(in_array($needle,$data) )
   echo $needle . " found";
else
   echo $needle . " not found";
```

Comment: Offtopic, but I have always found funny the `return the freaking data or die` in `PHP`.

Comment: have you tried "$data= $row1;" rather than "$data[]= $row1;"

Comment: Katie, does `$data` show the data when you dump it? If yes, it's probably failing due to a type mismatch. Your needle is an int, while the array probably holds it as a string.

Comment: @DennisMartinez: That will just make her rewrite the value stored in $data on every iteration of the loop.

Comment: @xbonez Ah yup! Sorry about that, ignore what I had said.

Answer (score 4):

$data is a multi-dimensional array, though in_array expects a one-dimensional array.
Did you mean:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT num FROM staff";
$data = array();
     $result1 = mysql_query($sql1, $conn) or die("db select error: " . $sql1);
      while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)){
          $data[]= $row1['num'];
      }
var_dump($data);

$needle = 7034252;
if(in_array($needle,$data) )
   echo $needle . " found";
else
   echo $needle . " not found";
```

This code could be shorter (and more efficient) though:

```
$needle = 7034252;
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM staff WHERE num = " . mysql_real_escape_string($needle);
if (mysql_result(sql, 0) > 0)
   echo $needle . " found";
else
   echo $needle . " not found";
```

Answer (score -1):

Not tested, but why don't you try something like this?

```
$sql1 = "SELECT num FROM staff";
$result1 = mysql_query($sql1, $conn) or die("db select error: " . $sql1);
$needle = 7034252;
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
{
   if ($needle == $row1['num'])
   {
      echo $needle . " found";
   }
}
```

Comment: Your if condition should be `$needle == $row['num']` or you're comparing an int to an array.

Comment: @xbonez Yep, just saw that I missed that and was editing it... thanks!

Comment: So granted, @Sander's second answer above is more efficient, but why the downvote?